# I'm trying to add firebase sdk into android project

Tags: android, gradle

I want to add **firebase sdk** into an **android project**.
I'm watching google firebase sdk site, and trying to add,
but an error occurs during synchronizing gradle file.
It says library version isn't match, but I don't know how to make it match.
I tried  downgrading target sdk version. It doesn't work.
How can I fix it?
Thank you in advance.

[image: error]
gradle file code

[image: error description]
its error description

[image: google firebase sdk example]
I copied those codes.

Comment: Please read the Firebase documentation again (not an outdated video). The latest version is not `11.x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the version to these

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

and

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

always use latest version from firebase [website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

and also check if you are using latest support library version according to your targetSdkVersion.